# Convert 32bit data to unsigned long value

Tags: java, binary, byte, shift

I have something like this:

```
int[0] = 4123; 
int[1] = 2571;
```

I would like to combine them and make one long value in Java.
This is my attempt:

```
int[] r = { 4123, 2571 };
long result = ( (r[1] & 0xFFFF) << 16 | (rs[0] & 0xFFFF) );
System.out.prinln(result);
```

The output should be: 10111627 but I get 168497179. Probably I miss something in conversion but don't have idea what...

**EDIT**

This is example how the value is placed into 32-bit register.

[image]

Comment: 10111627 is not made up out of 4123 and 2571 no matter how I look at it. In hex the small parts are 0x101b and 0x0a0b, I can't turn that into 0x009a4a8b in any reasonable way. How do you know what the output should be? Is that part even correct to begin with?

Comment: Your code is correct. Your test is wrong.

Comment: Please see my updated post. There is image that show how the value is stored into 32-bit register and how I get that the result shoud be 10111627

Comment: Are you sure you should get 10111627? Wolfram thinks otherwise: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1010000010110001000000011011

Comment: This is not how base conversion works, the result really is 0x0a0b101e aka 168497179, but you're reinterpreting it as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I try the summarize and hopefully clarify what the several comments on your question already indicate:

If you want to get the number from your image which is
`00001010 00001011 00010000 00011011` = `0x0A0B101B` = `168497179`
in one single `long` value and you have two ints
`0001000000011011` = `0x101B` = `4123` and
`0000101000001011` = `0x0A0B` = `2571`
than your **code is correct**.

I would recommend you to get used to hexadecimal numbers as they show easily that there is no binary relation between `0x0A0B` & `0x101B` and `0x009A4A8B` = `10111627`.

BTW your image is contradictory: the binary numbers represent as seen above the number `0x0A0B101B` but the hexadecimals read `0x0A0B101E` *(notice the `E`)* while the decimals support the binary value.

**Finally, I figured out your flaw:**

You seem to expect to get the decimal number concatenated together as result. But unlike the hexadecimals here it does *not* work this way in decimal!

Let me elaborate that. You have the binary number:
`00001010 00001011 00010000 00011011`
Which you can easily convert to hex block by block
`0x0A     0x0B     0x10     0x1B`
and than just join them together
`0x0A0B101B`

But that magic join is just a simplification only applying to hex (and the reason why hex is so popular among programmers).

The long version is you have to multiply the higher blocks/bytes (towards the left) with the *'basis'* of the preceding block (to the right). The right most block is always multiplied by `1`. The base for the next block is (since there are `8` bits in the first block) 2<sup>8</sup> = `256` = `0x100`. The base for the third block is (`8+8` bits) 2<sup>16</sup> = `65536` = `0x10000`. The last (left most) has to be multiplied by (`8+8+8` bits) 2<sup>24</sup> = `16777216` = `0x1000000`.

Lets make an example for the first two blocks:

Hexadecimal:
`0x10`  ||  `0x1B`
`(0x10 * 0x100) + (0x1B* 0x1)`
`0x1000 + 0x1B` = **`0x101B`**

Decimal:
`16` || `27`
`(16 * 256) + (27 * 1)`
`4096 + 27` = **`4123`**

As you can see on your image they both in it *(notice the `E`/`B` issue which is in decimal a `6`/`3` issue)* but there is no `1627`. So converting binary or hexadecimal numbers to decimal is a nontrivial task (for humans), best to use a calculator.